# How to dynamically change the module name in the render function

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I would like to be able to dynamically choose the module name in my render function inside a template. So I tried this but I'm getting errors:

```
<%= render if i.compType == "mod" do MyProj.ModuleView else MyProj.ComponentView end, i.compName %>
```

The final result would be:

```
<%= render MyProj.ModuleView, "module.html" %>
```

or

```
<%= render MyProj.ComponentView, "component.html" %>
```

What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing a pair of parentheses:

```
<%= render (if i.compType == "mod" do MyProj.ModuleView else MyProj.Component end), i.compName %>
```

A more idiomatic way though would be to use the form without `end`:

```
<%= render if(i.compType == "mod", do: MyProj.ModuleView, else: MyProj.Component), i.compName %>
```